# Why app script returns one value less then the value in the cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What did I do wrong.  I have an google sheet with a date in a cell and when I run my script it's returning the day before the date I have in the cell.

```
function EmailPDF() {
   var spreadSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Project Info');
   var ds = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dailys');
   var date = ds.getRange('J8').getValue();

MailApp.sendEmail(se, pn, 'See Attachement for ' + dn + ' - ' + date + " daily.", {
```

My var date is returning the day before.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Perhaps your script and your spreadsheet are setup for difference time zones.

Answer (score 0):

Use getDisplayValue() instead.

> getDisplayValue() returns the displayed value of the top-left cell in the range. The
> value is a String. The displayed value takes into account date, time
> and currency formatting formatting, including formats applied
> automatically by the spreadsheet's locale setting. Empty cells return
> an empty string.

**From:**

```
var date = ds.getRange('J8').getValue();
```

**To:**

```
var date = ds.getRange('J8').getDisplayValue();
```

Reference:

- [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)

Comment: @JoshLawrenz - Was my answer above able to fix your issue? If yes, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)